# VBA How to copy rows from on Workbook to another with condition

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have one master workbook with all the raw data. Column B of this is either empty or contains the text "Yes".

I have another workbook which has to contain all rows of the master workbook which contain "Yes" in the B column.

Each time the macro runs, I need to empty my second filtered workbook and check the master workbook from row 1.

How can I achieve this using VBA?

**Edit 1**: this is the code I have been working on

```
Sub filter()

Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

If Cells(i, 1) = Date And Cells(i, 2) = “Yes” Then
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 7)).Select
Selection.Copy

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\212557423\Desktop\2.xls"
Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Select
erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If

Next i
End Sub
```

**Edit2**: After some more research I have following code:

```
Sub filter()
Dim strsearch As String, lastline As Integer, tocopy As Integer

lastline = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
j = 1

For i = 1 To lastline
    For Each c In Range("B" & i)
        If InStr(c.Text, "ja") Then
            Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c
Next i

End Sub
```

My problem now is that this macro only copies from one sheet to another. What I need is for the "slave" workbook to fetch rows from the "master" workbook.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code and what has / hasn't worked for you.... We're more than happy to help guide you, but won't write the code for you

Comment: Give it a try first, post what you have and we can help you fix it.  Start by developing a plan with simple steps e.g. 1: Open masterWb and otherWb.  2: Loop across all cells in column B of otherWb and check the corresponding cell in masterWb etc...

Comment: I edited my first post with my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

edit: just to add the warning that, as you asked for, the filtered workbook **is always emptied** before adding current filtered values from raw data worksheet

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim rawDataSht As Worksheet, filtDataSht As Worksheet

    Set rawDataSht = ActiveSheet
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\212557423\Desktop\2.xls"
    Set filtDataSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With rawDataSht
        With .Range("A1:G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
            .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="YES"
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then
                filtDataSht.Cells.Clear
                .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy
                filtDataSht.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Else
                MsgBox "No data with ""YES"" in column B of sheet " & .Parent.name & " of workbook " & .Parent.Parent.name
            End If
            .AutoFilter
        End With
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks better than my solutions.
I get error 1004 though and I can't recognize why...

Comment: This one: `.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="YES"`

Comment: when you start the macro is the sheet with raw data actually the "active" one? has it data from columns "A" to "G"?

Comment: Yes, the sheet with raw data is active and hast data from A to G. I realized that although I get that error message, the data on the sheet is filtered and all rows without 'yes' are hidden.

Comment: is the sheet protected?

Comment: that shouldn't matter. but is it protected?

Comment: No. It is not protected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113658/discussion-between-user3598756-and-julian-m).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different way of accomplishing your task.

```
    With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With Range("B1", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("YES"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
            On Error Resume Next
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
        End With
    Workbooks("C:\Users\212557423\Desktop\2.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
```